# How to allow user input on tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi I'm a beginner in Python and I'm working on a chatbot interface using tkinter. The problem i'm having is that I can't seem to type in the window after asking “Hi there, what’s your name?”. Instead, the conversation continues to the next line, stating Hi (the first entry stated) would you like to purchase a ticket?

Is there a way to allow user to enter their name, then after that, state the entry?

For example:

> User: Hi
>
> Bot: Hi there, what’s your name?
>
> User: Tom
>
> Bot: Hi Tom, would you like to purchase a ticket?

At the moment the program goes like this:

> User: hi
>
> Bot: Hi there, what’s your name?
>
> Bot: Hi hi would you like to purchase a ticket?

I'm not sure what is causing the Bot to state another statement, before allowing user input, I've thought of storing name in name_var using StringVar(), then use that variable in the next line, but that didn't work.. any ideas how to fix this?

This is the code I have so far:

````
# Representing the parent window
root = Tk() 

#Title of window
root.title('Chatbot') 

#Function to send the message 
def send(): 
send = "You =>" + entry.get() 
text.insert(END, "\n" + send) if(entry.get()=="Hi" or entry.get()=="hi" or entry.get()=="Hi there" or entry.get()=="hi there" or entry.get()=="Hello" or entry.get()== "hello"):
text.insert(END, "\n" + "Bot => Hi there, whats your name ?") 
name_var = str(StringVar()) 
text.insert(END, "\n" + "Bot => Hi " + name_var + " would you like to purchase a ticket?") 
else: 
text.insert(END, "\n" + "Bot => Sorry, I have no answer") 
entry.delete(0, END) text = Text(root) 

# Adding dimensions and send button of window 
text.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2) 
entry = Entry(root, width=100) 
send = Button(root, text="Send", command=send).grid(row=1, column=1) entry.grid(row=1, column=0)
root.mainloop()```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `send` callback, you just add the two messages right after another, without waiting for user input in between. Instead, you could split that in two: A generator function, `yield`ing the next line in a complex conversation tree, and the `send` message just caring about putting that next message into the text field:

```
from tkinter import *

def message_generator():
    if entry.get().lower() in ("hi", "hi there", "hello"):
        # ask for name
        yield "Hi there, whats your name ?"
        # greeting with name
        name_var = entry.get()
        yield "Hi " + name_var + " would you like to purchase a ticket?" 
        # more conversation, possibly with diverging branches
        # if entry.get() == "yes": ...
    else: 
        yield "Sorry, I have no answer"

def send(): 
    text.insert(END, "\nYou =>" + entry.get())
    text.insert(END, "\nBot =>" + next(msg_gen))
    entry.delete(0, END)

msg_gen = message_generator()
    
root = Tk() 
root.title('Chatbot') 
text = Text(root) 
text.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2) 
entry = Entry(root, width=100) 
entry.grid(row=1, column=0)
Button(root, text="Send", command=send).grid(row=1, column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

The main point here is that the `message_generator` will not be executed fully. When you first call the function, it just creates a generator instance; then when you call `next` in `send`, it executes the generator function up to the next `yield` statement *and pauses there*, picking up execution from that same point the next time `next` is called, thus providing a nice way to keep track of the current state of the conversation.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this makes sense. So is it best to always create separate functions in Python, rather than repeating the You=> and Bot=> parts multiple time during conversation? And for the first line in message_generator(), what does the ‘entry.get().lower()’ mean? And in terms of the diverging branches, does that mean, to continue the conversation via if-else statements, possibly for better readability?

Comment: Here, the separate functions are not so much to reduce repetition (that's a nice side effect though) but really so that the one can be a _generator_ function, which is not executed fully, but "paused" after the yield and then continued from that point. Maybe I should have stressed that more, as that's the main take-away point here. And yes, you'd probably continue that function with a bunch of possibly nested if/else statements.